# Java spark example runs wrong with error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$scope()Lscala/xml/TopScope$

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nosuchmethod

I wrote a example with `spark maven` support in `Intelligent IDEA`.
The `spark` version is 2.0.0, `hadoop` version is 2.7.3, `scala` version is 2.11.8. Enviroment in system and IDE is the same version. Then application runs with error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   `scala.Predef$.$scope()Lscala/xml/TopScope$`;     at
>   `org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.StagePage`.(StagePage.scala:44)   at
>   `org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.StagesTab`.(StagesTab.scala:34)   at
>   `org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI`.(SparkUI.scala:62)    at
>   `org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:215)`  at
>   `org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.createLiveUI(SparkUI.scala:157)`    at
>   `org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:443)`    at
>   `org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:149)`    at
>   `org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:185)`    at
>   `org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:92)`
>     at `com.spark.test.WordCountTest.main(WordCountTest.java:25)`   at
>   `sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`     at
>   `sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)`
>     at
>   `sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)`
>     at `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)`   at
>   `com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)`

Comment: There's a version mismatch somewhere. Check your cluster, sbt, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Spark 2.0.0 build with scala 2.10, you have to add scala 2.10 as framework support

Answer (score 0):

Update `pom.xml` with `scala 2.11.8`.
See the spark download documentation for version compatibility.